# Difference between `\lhd` and `\triangleleft`

Tags: symbols, relation-symbols

I recently learned the command `\lhd`, which can be used for denoting normal subgroups. But what is the difference of `\lhd` compared to `\triangleleft`? Similarly, what is the difference between `\unlhd` and `\trianglelefteq`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you load `amssymb` and `amsfonts` then the definitions are

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lhd}           {\mathbin}{AMSa}{"43}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\unlhd}         {\mathbin}{AMSa}{"45}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vartriangleleft}{\mathrel}{AMSa}{"43}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\trianglelefteq}{\mathrel}{AMSa}{"45}
```

so the `lhd` names (which came originally from `latexsym`) use the same characters from the font but with the `\mathbin` spacing (like +) as opposed to the `\mathrel` spacing (like =)